# Is "the tide of people" a meaningful and natural phrase?

Tags: word-usage

> Unemployment rate is progressively increasing, and the government has failed to stem the tide of unemployed people.

In this sentence, I want to say that the number of people who are made redundant is increasing and governments has failed to stop this trend. Is the phrase "tide of unemployed people" natural to be used?

In dictionaries, I have seen that this phrase is used for things not for people, so I guess it is better to rewrite the sentence like this:

> Unemployment rate is progressively increasing, and the government has failed to stem the tide of redundancies.

Comment: I don't think so, unless they are moving in or out or somewhere in a coordinated way.

Comment: I agree that "tide" suggests movement or change.  I don't see how the *people* are a "tide".

Comment: "The tide of unemployed people" is meaningful. It suggests that more and more just keep showing up, unendingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just say as a native that this use of "tide of" is provocative language that you might read in a tabloid. With that in mind, "tide of people" does make sense. It certainly makes as much sense as "tide of redundancies". In both of these cases you're implying that there is a large* amount of unemployed people/redundancies and the government has failed to reduce the number of them.

*You could interpret it to mean overwhelmingly large; the phrase leaves a lot of people with the mental image of a tidal wave.